# Click event not firing after closing pop-up in leafletjs

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using leafletjs with Openstreetmaps and show a popup on click.

If I click on the map popups are opened.

But why is a click event not fired if I close the current popup first? (in that case I need to click two times on the map to open a new popup)

```js
// center of the map
var ll = [-37.8136, 144.9631];
var layers = [
  // add the OSM layer
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    zoom: 18
  })
]

// map's options
var options = {
  center: ll,
  zoom: 12,
  scrollWheelZoom: false,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  layers: layers,
}

var map = L.map('map', options);


var popup = L.popup();

function onMapClick(e) {
  console.log("clicked on map");
  popup
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
    .openOn(map);
}

map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your question is on a strange behaviour in your snippet:

1. Click somewhere on the map to have a popup opened (as per your code).
2. Close the popup by clicking on its top right cross.
3. Try to open a new popup somewhere by clicking on the (now popup-free) map. => the first click does not fire the click event (hence it does not open the popup). A second click behaves as expected (i.e. like in step 1). If you skip step 2, the first click behaves as expected.

This is probably a bug in Leaflet in version 0.6.4 that you are using.

Current stable version is 0.7.7 and it works as you expect for your case:

```js
// center of the map
var ll = [-37.8136, 144.9631];
var layers = [
  // add the OSM layer
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    zoom: 18
  })
]

// map's options
var options = {
  center: ll,
  zoom: 12,
  scrollWheelZoom: false,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  layers: layers,
}

var map = L.map('map', options);


var popup = L.popup();

function onMapClick(e) {
  console.log("clicked on map");
  popup
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
    .openOn(map);
}

map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```